# django feed reader

Tags: python, django, feed

I want to create in django something close to feed reader. It should download the xml data, parse it into python objects save it in database and update those objects if feed will be updated.

If there is a app that might be helpfull for me ?
If is it soo, does it works with Windows while developing ?

Please, post me how can I cope with that issue.

Answer (score 5):

maybe this project be helpful

- tghw / django-feedreader / overview — Bitbucket ->
  https://bitbucket.org/tghw/django-feedreader/

and yes you can use django project in windows

- Setup Django on Windows with Apache and MySQL in 15 mins - Venky's Blog -> http://www.venkysblog.com/setup-django-on-windows-with-apache-and-mysql
- howto:django_on_windows [Thinkhole Labs Wiki] -> http://wiki.thinkhole.org/howto:django_on_windows

Answer (score 1):

NewsBlur is a full featured news reader that is open source: https://github.com/samuelclay/NewsBlur

It should be possible to get it running on Windows.

As a full solution, it looks fairly heavyweight.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the project [TNB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thenewsbook/), but it is written in `C#`.

Comment: Could you give an short explanation of `TNB` (it can be quoted) and the benefit you would get using it over other solutions?

Comment: hey nick,,, actully TNB is an open source project on sourceforge.net.it is a article extractr(specially for news websites)feed readers just read the rss feeds and give the page url of the websites,,but TNB give only the main article by extracting the webpage,,, u can than format the article text to show in a web browser or in a richtextbox or in any other editor,,,by using TNB api's.u can contact me at dce.aslam@gmail.com,,,or can see the project on www.sourceforge.net/projects/thenewsbook